# Html src = a php variable

Tags: php, html, variables, iframe, src

Hello I looked around a bit for a solution but couldn't find someone with the exact problem as me. Basically I have a php variable that is a url. I want to add a new iframe with that url.

This is what I have, but because HTML is using the double quotes after src the php variable is ignored.

```
<iframe width="420" height="345"src= "<?php $output ?>"> </iframe>
```

Thank you guys

Comment: Answers below (you forgot the `echo`), but just saying that HTML can also use single quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($output); ?>"> </iframe>
```

You're missing `echo`.  Also, always use `htmlspecialchars()` to ensure you are creating valid HTML that isn't vulnerable to injection.  If you find yourself doing this a lot, consider using a template engine.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked wonderfully. Most of the work that I have done in the past has all been offline games and such. Haven't done much with online work. I was unfamiliar with htmlspecialchars. What exactly does that do?

Comment: @Brad [Since PHP 5.4, `<?php echo` can be safely replaced with `<?=`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php). Previous versions required [`short_open_tag` or `asp_tags` to be `on`](http://php.net/ini.core); the former caused problems with XML, but with the latter you could use `<%=` instead.

Comment: @user3369289 It will take characters like `<` and `>` and convert them to `&lt;` and `&gt;` to make sure they aren't interpreted as HTML.  You don't want text content to leak to your HTML.  In worse cases, if you are outputting text from users, it might contain `<script>` tags.

Comment: Interesting I will look into this! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($output); ?>"> </iframe>
```